# Loop Join in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, left-join, join-hints

I'm not clear about working difference between queries mentioned below.

> Specifically I'm unclear about the concept of `OPTION(LOOP JOIN)`.

**1st approach:** it's a traditional join used, which is most expensive than all of below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Item Detail] a
LEFT JOIN [Order Detail] b ON a.[ItemId] = b.[fkItemId] OPTION (FORCE ORDER);
```

**2nd approach:** It includes `OPTION` in a statement with sorted data, merely optimized.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Item Detail] a
LEFT LOOP JOIN [Order Detail] b ON a.[ItemId] = b.[fkItemId] OPTION (FORCE ORDER);
```

**3rd approach:** Here, I am not clear, how the query works and includes `OPTION` with `loop join`!!?

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Item Detail] a
LEFT LOOP JOIN [Order Detail] b ON a.[ItemId] = b.[fkItemId] OPTION (LOOP JOIN);
```

Can anybody explain difference and way of working and advantages of each one over other?

*Note:* These are **not** Nested OR Hash loops!

Comment: documentation: [Query Hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) and [Join Hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173815.aspx)

Comment: Why do you think 1st approach is "most expensive than all of below"?

Comment: I tested it with my local server and got highest difference for it! and of course, difference was of +2 to +3 seconds only

Comment: By not specifying any hint you let SQL server determine what kind of join type to use which is usually the best. Sometimes if the statistics are outdated a wrong plan might be used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Query Hints (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx)

> FORCE ORDER Specifies that the join order indicated by the query
>   syntax is preserved during query optimization. Using FORCE ORDER does
>   not affect possible role reversal behavior of the query optimizer.

also

> { LOOP | MERGE | HASH } JOIN Specifies that all join operations are
>   performed by LOOP JOIN, MERGE JOIN, or HASH JOIN in the whole query.
>   If more than one join hint is specified, the optimizer selects the
>   least expensive join strategy from the allowed ones.

[Advanced Query Tuning Concepts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191426(v=sql.105).aspx)

> If one join input is small (fewer than 10 rows) and the other join
>   input is fairly large and indexed on its join columns, an index nested
>   loops join is the fastest join operation because they require the
>   least I/O and the fewest comparisons.
>
> If the two join inputs are not small but are sorted on their join
>   column (for example, if they were obtained by scanning sorted
>   indexes), a merge join is the fastest join operation.
>
> Hash joins can efficiently process large, unsorted, nonindexed inputs.

And [Join Hints (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms173815.aspx)

> Join hints specify that the query optimizer enforce a join strategy
>   between two tables

Your option 1 tells the optimizer to keep the join order as is. So the `JOIN` type can be decided by the optimizer, so might be `MERGE JOIN`.

You option 2 is telling the optimizer to use `LOOP JOIN` for this specific `JOIN`. If there were any other joins in the `FROM` section, the optimizer would be able to decide for them. Also, you are specifying the order of JOINS to take for the optimizer.

Your last option `OPTION (LOOP JOIN)` would enforce `LOOP JOIN` across all joins in the query.

*This all said, it is very seldom that the optimizer would choose an incorrect plan, and this should probably indicate bigger underlying issues, such as outdated statistics or fragmented indexes.*